# Passing data from database to textbox in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I was trying to pass the data from table to my view's textbox. here's my code:

**view**

```
$("#tbledit").click(function(){
    if(tblingridacc.g.getSelectedRowIds()==""){
        alert("No entry to be update.\nPlease select an entry from the table and try again!");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/ict_onclick/accountedtTblSelected/'+tblingridacc.g.getSelectedRowIds(),
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.username);
                $("#tbxAccUN").val(data.username);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**controller**

```
function accountedtTblSelected($id=null){

$qry = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM tblaccounts WHERE id = '$id'");
$qry = $qry->row_array();
echo json_encode($qry);
}
```

**EDIT:** everything is running good but the textbox is empty. :-( please help!

Comment: Then what was the error ?

Comment: Can you please explain in brief what's your issue

Comment: editted already

Comment: So e everything running good means you can see the correct json response ie either firebug or whatever you are using to debug this... Can you provide that :)

Comment: the query is okay base on the response... but seems like I need to refresh the page for this textbox to contain the data. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.sttringify

```
success:function(data){
data = JSON.stringify(data);
   alert(data.username);
   $("#tbxAccUN").val(data.username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error. LOL! textbox name and ID is duplicated which the data from database passes to the first textbox thats why the 2nd textbox is empty. my apologies guys xD

> tbxAccUN

Comment: Well I wasn't just about to suggest that :) That is grand that you got it working!